# How to assign a list of integers as the parameter value for an oracle command parameter in the where clause?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, odp.net

I have a query like 
Select * from tablename where id in (:ids);

I want to assign a list of integers for the above parameter :ids.
I am using the ODP.Net with C#.

`The code snippet will be something like this`

```
const String sql = Select * from tablename where id in (:ids);

using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, dbc)) {
cmd.Parameters.Add(:ids, OracleDbType.Int64, 12, Ids , ParameterDirection.Input);
using(OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
}
}
```

But its throwing some errors...

Can anybody please help on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you need to bind them one by one:

```
vat sql = string.Format("select * from tablename where id in ({0})", string.Join(",", ids.Select((v,i)=>":id"+i)));
using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sql, dbc)) {
    int pos = 0;
    foreach (var id in Ids) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("id"+pos, OracleDbType.Int64, 12, id , ParameterDirection.Input);
        pos++;
    }
    using(OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader()) {
        ...
    }
}
```

First, you construct the SQL that looks like `"... where id in (id0, id1, id2, ...)"`, then go through the actual IDs one by one in a `foreach` loop, and bind them to the command.